# Private messages database query for display

Tags: php, mysql

ok I have messages table in db like this:

```
id
thread_id
from_user
to_user
message
```

the problem I have is display of these messages on site. As would be normal with private messages, only receiver and sender can see the message. And there is one more thing that matters, messages are thread related, so when sender contacts the user who created a thread ( user can send messages only to thread creators, every user who would be contacted MUST have a thread he created) this conversation is related to this thread only. So, check now what I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM messages 
WHERE thread_id = '$thread_id' 
    AND (from_user = '$from' OR from_user ='$to' ) 
    AND ( to_user = '$to' OR to_user = '$from' )
```

This works in majority of cases, but what I was wondering is if this is classic query which is used to limit only to users to view the message?

```
$thread_id is ID of the thread passed to query
$from is $_SESSION['id'] 
$to is ID of thread owner ( user who receives the message )
```

I tested this with few users but something is not right. Sometimes I get only 1 message that one sent, but don't see the reply

Comment: So i didn't understood. What is exact problem?

Comment: have you made sure that the correct `from_user`, `to_user` and `thread_id` are stored next to the messages you expect to see but aren't being displayed?

Comment: @vinculis I already said, this query is not right, it displays multiple answers for user in few cases. I will check the problem exactly and edit the question